# Descargar archivo txt en php fwrite

Tags: php

estoy tratando de generar un archivo en txt. Actualmente lo descargo a una carpeta en el servidor pero quiero forzar la descarga. Ya tengo el código pero me salen un error, espero me puedan ayudar a encontrar la solución.

Este es mi código:

```
$file = $tpoPoliza.$fechaInicial.'-'.$fechaFinal.'.txt';

$fp = fopen($directorio.$file, "a" )or die("Unable to open file!");

$registroDet = $tpoRegistro . $separator . $ctaContable. $separator. $separator. $separator. 
$separator . $importe . $separator . $separator . $moneda. $separator. $separator. $separator. 
$separator. $posPre . $separator . $separator . $separator . $separator. $txtPosicion . 
$separator. $separator . $separator . $asignacion . $jump;



 fwrite($fp, $registroDet);

fclose($fp);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
readfile($file);
```

Y este es el error que me sale.
Como lo puedo solucionar. Espero me puedan ayudar.

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\plantilla.php:134) in C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\modulos\polizaSAP.php on line 144

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\plantilla.php:134) in C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\modulos\polizaSAP.php on line 145

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\plantilla.php:134) in C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\modulos\polizaSAP.php on line 146

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\plantilla.php:134) in C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\modulos\polizaSAP.php on line 147

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\plantilla.php:134) in C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\modulos\polizaSAP.php on line 148

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for 1-Ventanilla Oficina2020-07-01-2020-07-31.txt in C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\modulos\polizaSAP.php on line 149

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\plantilla.php:134) in C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\modulos\polizaSAP.php on line 149

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\plantilla.php:134) in C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\modulos\polizaSAP.php on line 150

Warning: readfile(1-Ventanilla Oficina2020-07-01-2020-07-31.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\vistas\modulos\polizaSAP.php on line 151

Comment: Los mensajes de error son claros. Cuando usas `header` no debe haber antes ninguna salida por pantalla. Dado que estás incluyendo archivos de varias partes, alguno de ellos tiene salida por pantalla, concretamente el archivo `plantilla.php` Tienes que organizar mejor el código para que eso no ocurra.

Comment: Algún ejemplo??

Answer (score 1):

a la siguiente instruccion le falta un parentesis al final

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/332075)

Answer (score 0):

No puedes enviar salida HTML y descargar archivo en la misma petición. Genera la página como lo haces normalmente y usa javascript para redirigir a otra página, que manejará la descarga.

```
$file = $tpoPoliza.$fechaInicial.'-'.$fechaFinal.'.txt';
$fp = fopen($directorio.$file, "a" )or die("Unable to open file!");

$registroDet = $tpoRegistro . $separator . $ctaContable. $separator. $separator. $separator. 
$separator . $importe . $separator . $separator . $moneda. $separator. $separator. $separator. 
$separator. $posPre . $separator . $separator . $separator . $separator. $txtPosicion . 
$separator. $separator . $separator . $asignacion . $jump;

fwrite($fp, $registroDet);
fclose($fp);
?>
<script>
// Especifica la ruta correcta para el nuevo script
// Solo envía el nombre del archivo, sin directorio
window.location.href = '/ruta/descarga.php?file=<?php echo $file; ?>';
</script>
```

**descarga.php**

```
<?php
// Define el directorio igual que hiciste al crear el archivo
$directorio = '/ruta/';
// Valida el archivo recibido, eliminando caracteres no permitidos y diagonales para evitar retrocesos en ruta
$file = (isset($_GET['file'])) ? str_replace('/', '', filter_var($_GET['file'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)) : '';
// Separar para obtener extensión
$partes = explode('.', $file);
// No se especificó el archivo, no es .txt o no existe
if($file == '' || end($partes) != 'txt' || !file_exists($directorio . $file)) {
    die('Archivo no encontrado');
}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file;
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($directorio . $file));
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
readfile($directorio . $file);
```

Seguramente hay mejores opciones para sanear la entrada de datos para evitar descarga de archivos no permitidos, pero ya te tocará investigar.

Comment: no puedo cambiar el codigo en cuanto fopen() + fwrite() + fclose() tengo que usar forzosamente esas instrucciones.

Comment: No hay problema, esa era solo una sugerencia. Modifiqué la respuesta para eliminar la opción de _file_put_contents()_

Comment: en el script la ruta window.location.href = '/ruta/descarga.php?file=<?php echo $file; ?>'; es la ruta donde está alojado el archivo?

Comment: @PedroIslasReséndiz, `/ruta/descarga.php` es el script que tienes que crear para generar la descarga y solo le envías el nombre del archivo.

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error: Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\controladores\descarga.php on line 9

Comment: Sí, me equivoqué en el if, ya corregí la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, ya me descarga el archivo txt, aun que no me trae nada de infornacion, solo me sale el siguiente error: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\RecaudacionOk\controladores\descarga.php</b>
 on line <b>20</b><br />

Comment: Revisa que estás enviando ruta y nombre de archivo: en `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($directorio . $file));` y `readfile($directorio . $file);`

Comment: Gracias, ya quedó. Te agradezco mucho.